# Struggling with extracting values from XML data (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Here is a snippet of my XML data from the bottom of the file showing the end tags (it's a huge file):

```
<EncounterValidationResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.dhcs.ca.gov/EDS/DHCSResponse" ResponseVersion="1.2">
  <EncounterFileName>EncounterFileName</EncounterFileName>
  <EncounterSubmitterName>EncounterSubmitter</EncounterSubmitterName>
  <EncounterSubmissionDate>2019-12-13T08:47:00.0000000-08:00</EncounterSubmissionDate>
  <ValidationStatus>Accepted</ValidationStatus>
  <Transactions>
    <Transaction>
      <IdentifierName>BatchNumber</IdentifierName>
      <TransactionNumber>1277104</TransactionNumber>
      <Identifiers>
        <Envelope IdentifierName="OriginatorTransactionId" IdentifierValue="1277104-00" />
      </Identifiers>
      <Encounters>
        <Encounter Status="Accepted">
          <IdentifierType>TransactionIdentifier</IdentifierType>
          <EncounterReferenceNumber>8129339999264</EncounterReferenceNumber>
          <EncounterId>1934049991539</EncounterId>
          <EncounterResponses>
            <Response Severity="Warning">
              <Id>0x0006D</Id>
              <Description>MEDS indicates multiple records exist for this beneficiary</Description>
            </Response>
            <Response Severity="Warning">
              <Id>0x00221</Id>
              <Description>Prescriber Taxonomy (296)  is either not provided or is invalid</Description>
            </Response>
            <Response Severity="Warning">
              <Id>0x00249</Id>
              <Description>Reason for Service Code (439-E4) is requested per the payer sheet but no value is provided/specified.</Description>
            </Response>
            <Response Severity="Warning">
              <Id>0x00249</Id>
              <Description>Professional Service Code (440-E5) is requested per the payer sheet but no value is provided/specified.</Description>
            </Response>
            <Response Severity="Warning">
              <Id>0x00249</Id>
              <Description>Result of Service Code (441-E6) is requested per the payer sheet but no value is provided/specified.</Description>
            </Response>
          </EncounterResponses>
        </Encounter>
      </Encounters>
    </Transaction>
  </Transactions>
</EncounterValidationResponse>
```

I'm trying to extract all Encounter Status values, EncounterReferenceNumbers, Response Severity values, Id and Description values. I would like the query to return five columns, Encounter Status, Encounter Reference Number, Severity, Id, and Description.

I've been searching the internet for days and have tried several things but can't seem to get it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This isn't a valid XML. Correct it to include missing opening tags.

Comment: Is this better now? The file is huge so I can't post the entire file.

Comment: Yes, it's quite clear now. Namespaces are essential part of the XML data so you can't create a correct query without knowing this info.See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this demo:

```
declare @x XML='<EncounterValidationResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.dhcs.ca.gov/EDS/DHCSResponse" ResponseVersion="1.2">
  <EncounterFileName>EncounterFileName</EncounterFileName>
  <EncounterSubmitterName>EncounterSubmitter</EncounterSubmitterName>
  <EncounterSubmissionDate>2019-12-13T08:47:00.0000000-08:00</EncounterSubmissionDate>
  <ValidationStatus>Accepted</ValidationStatus>
  <Transactions>
    <Transaction>
      <IdentifierName>BatchNumber</IdentifierName>
      <TransactionNumber>1277104</TransactionNumber>
      <Identifiers>
        <Envelope IdentifierName="OriginatorTransactionId" IdentifierValue="1277104-00" />
      </Identifiers>
      <Encounters>
        <Encounter Status="Accepted">
          <IdentifierType>TransactionIdentifier</IdentifierType>
          <EncounterReferenceNumber>8129339999264</EncounterReferenceNumber>
          <EncounterId>1934049991539</EncounterId>
          <EncounterResponses>
            <Response Severity="Warning">
              <Id>0x0006D</Id>
              <Description>MEDS indicates multiple records exist for this beneficiary</Description>
            </Response>
            <Response Severity="Warning">
              <Id>0x00221</Id>
              <Description>Prescriber Taxonomy (296)  is either not provided or is invalid</Description>
            </Response>
            <Response Severity="Warning">
              <Id>0x00249</Id>
              <Description>Reason for Service Code (439-E4) is requested per the payer sheet but no value is provided/specified.</Description>
            </Response>
            <Response Severity="Warning">
              <Id>0x00249</Id>
              <Description>Professional Service Code (440-E5) is requested per the payer sheet but no value is provided/specified.</Description>
            </Response>
            <Response Severity="Warning">
              <Id>0x00249</Id>
              <Description>Result of Service Code (441-E6) is requested per the payer sheet but no value is provided/specified.</Description>
            </Response>
          </EncounterResponses>
        </Encounter>
      </Encounters>
    </Transaction>
  </Transactions>
</EncounterValidationResponse>';


with xmlnamespaces (DEFAULT 'http://www.dhcs.ca.gov/EDS/DHCSResponse') 
select  t.n.value('@Status','nvarchar(100)') status,
     t.n.value('EncounterReferenceNumber[1]','nvarchar(100)') EncounterReferenceNumber,
     r.n.value('@Severity','nvarchar(100)') Severity,
     r.n.value('Id[1]','nvarchar(100)') Id,
     r.n.value('Description[1]','nvarchar(100)') Description
from @x.nodes('/EncounterValidationResponse/Transactions/Transaction/Encounters/Encounter') t(n)
cross apply t.n.nodes('EncounterResponses/Response') r(n);
```

Comment: Wow!! PERFECT!! This is exactly what I wanted. I wish I had asked for help much sooner; however, I did learn a lot along the way. Serg, I truly appreciate your quick and accurate response. Thank you, thank you, thank you.